# Change certain <ul> and <li> (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, html-lists

I'm just starting to learn how to code with jQuery, javascript and so on and I wanted to ask if it's possible to change just a few certain `<ul>` and `<li>` to `<div>` and `<p>`.

I heard plugins are really often used and one of the biggest advantages of jquery so I thought I'd try to build one myself. Unfortunately I'm really new to programming so I don't know all the important stuff.

At the moment my plugin turns every `<div>` into an `<ul>` and my goal is to change the menu but not the moveable box. At the moment the script changes everything and as soon as the moveable div turns into an ul the buttons dissapear.

My HTML file has a menu and a box that is moveable with 2 buttons inside.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>List</title>
        <script type="text/javascript"
                src="jquery-1.10.2.js"> 
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"    
                src="plugins/jquery.replaceelements-1.0.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"  
                src="useplugin.js">
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            .green {
                color: green;
            }
            #menu {
                font-family: Arial;
            }
            #move, #base {
                padding: 5px;
                text-align: center;
                font-family: Arial;
                background-color: #99CCFF;
                border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
            }

            #move {
                padding: 50px;
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <ul id="menu">
            <li>Text 1</li>
            <li>Text 2</li>
            <li>Text 3</li>
            <li>Text 4</li>
            <li>Text 5</li>
            <li>Text 6</li>
        </ul>

        <div id="base">
            Click to Expand
        </div>
        <div id="move">
            <button id="format">Click to change format</button>
            <button id="color">Click to change color</button>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I use the following script to adapt the plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#format").click(function() {
        if ($("#menu").attr("class") == "changed") {
            $("#menu")
            .replaceReverse();
        }

        else {
            $("#menu")
            .replaceElements();

        }
    });
    $("#color").click(function() {
        $("#menu")
            .changeColor();
    });
    $("#base").click(function() {
        $("#move")
            .slideButton();
    });

});
```

and this is the plugin.

```
    ;(function($) {

    jQuery.fn.replaceElements = function(arg, callback) {

    var options = $.extend({},
                $.fn.replaceElements.defaults,
                arg,
                {callback:callback});

    return this.each(function() {
        replace(options,$(this).parent());
    });
    };
    function replace(opts, obj) {

    for (var i in opts) {

        $(obj).find(i).each(function() {

          var thisElement = $(this);


          thisElement.wrapInner("<" + opts[i] + " />");
          thisElement.children().addClass("changed");

          if(thisElement.attr("id")) {
             thisElement.children()
                       .attr("id",thisElement.attr("id"));
          }


          thisElement.children().unwrap();
        });
    }

    callFn(opts.callback);
  };
  function callFn (callback) {
    if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
        callback.call(this);
    }
  };

  $.fn.replaceElements.defaults = {

    ul: 'div',

    li: 'p'

  }

})(jQuery);

;(function($) {
  jQuery.fn.replaceReverse = function(arg, callback) {

  var options = $.extend({},
                $.fn.replaceReverse.defaults,
                arg,
                {callback:callback});
    return this.each(function() {
        replaceRev(options,$(this).parent());
    });
  };
  function replaceRev(opts, obj) {
    for (var i in opts) {

        $(obj).find(i).each(function() {

          var thisElement = $(this);
          console.log(opts[i]);

          thisElement.wrapInner("<" + opts[i] + " />");

          if(thisElement.attr("id")) {
             thisElement.children()
                       .attr("id",thisElement.attr("id"));
          }


          thisElement.children().unwrap();
        });
    }

    callFn(opts.callback);
  };
  function callFn (callback) {
    if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
        callback.call(this);
    }
  };

  $.fn.replaceReverse.defaults = {

    div: 'ul',

    p: 'li'

  }

})(jQuery);
```

I would be really thankful if one of you helped me with this (newbie) problem and I apologize for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you don't need `$(this).parent()` gives you `body` element, since `this` is the `#menu` item in your case, and the parent element will be `body` (which you don't want, since you only want to switch inner elements of menu).

When you click the first time, nothing bad happens, since your `#move` element is already a `div`.
But when you click it second time it switches alls `div`s to `ul` inside your `body` element.

A solution will be:

1. either change `$(this).parent()` to `$(this)`, but in this case you'll also have to handle the case for the `#menu` itself, since `$(obj).find` won't return you the `obj` itself
2. or leave it as is, but change your `$(obj).find` to something like 
   `$(obj).find('#' + id + ', #' + id + ' ' + i )`, where `id` = your target element id (so you'll have to introduce an additional parameter:  `replace(options,$(this).parent(), $(this).attr('id'));`